# Get last merged PR's branch name or PR number

Tags: git, github, github-actions

Is it possible to get branch name or PR number of the last merged branch to main, if yes how can we achieve this in github workflow file.

Use-case:
I am uploading an artifact when a PR is merged to main using a workflow, so while downloading i need to give the workflow and branch name to download it in other PRs.

I tried to find some github actions for this but could not find any

Comment: You're likely going to have to go thru the [Github REST API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest) for that information. To `git` a commit is just a commit, it has no internal concept of a Github pull request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're likely going to have to go thru the [Github REST API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest) for that information. To `git` a commit is just a commit, it has no internal concept of a Github pull request.

The following script assumes you have `curl` and `jq` installed, and that you have set up a personal access token.

See [Managing Your Personal Access Tokens](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/managing-your-personal-access-tokens)

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# GitHub repository owner and name
OWNER="owner_name"
REPO="repository_name"

# GitHub Personal Access Token
TOKEN="your_personal_access_token"

# Make a request to get the last merged pull request
response=$(curl -s -H "Authorization: token $TOKEN" \
    "https://api.github.com/repos/$OWNER/$REPO/pulls?state=closed&sort=updated&direction=desc&per_page=1")

# Extract pull request number from the response
pull_request_number=$(jq -r '.[0].number' <<<"$response")

echo "Last merged pull request number: $pull_request_number"
```